# Play streaming content using Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, networkstream, gst-launch

I wanted to use gstreamer for network steaming. Intention is to launch a video content (from Transmitter) and play it on receiver side.
I wrote a sample test code for steaming network content.

At transmitter side:
GST_DEBUG="*:2" gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5001

At Receiver side:
GST_DEBUG="*:2" gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink

At receiver I'm getting following error:

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.130187750  4589      0x1a690a0 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3669:gst_pad_peer_query: could not send sticky events
0:00:00.130796352  4589      0x1a690a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop: error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.130812589  4589      0x1a690a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop: error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.017176721
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Please guide me.
(note Im using Gstreamer in Ubuntu 14.04 PC. The same PC is being for transmitter and receiver purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy paste the caps like mentioned [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/gst/rtp/README#n251)