# GStreamer 1.16.2 UDP Sender and receiver "reason not-negotiated (-4)" error

Tags: udp, gstreamer, pipeline

I'm trying to receive a video source from an RTSP server and resend it through multiple UDP sockets. But to start I decided to try some examples from the internet. I've found this [link](https://z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/index.html)
where i did try the followings pipelines:

```
SENDER:
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200

RECEIVER:
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

I got the following output in the RECEIVER:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.010658578
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

So, the error is " reason not-negotiated (-4)". I tried several examples and this error comes up quite often. From what I found from several forums, the problem might be in the CAPS settings on the RECEIVER side. I gave a try to solve it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540084/play-streaming-content-using-gstreamer) without success (The caps are a copy of the same one returned by the SENDER):

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 caps = "image/jpeg, sof-marker=(int)0, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt601, chroma-site=(string)jpeg, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

The error here seems to be related to the pipeline construction itself:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link udpsrc0 to rtpjpegdepay0
```

I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and the GStreamer version 1.16.2

1 - What am i doing wrong?
2 - Do you have any idea of a "No latency" way to perform the "clone" of the RTSP video stream and send it through multiples UDP links?

Comment: Ok, i got this working but only in the windows 10. I've installed the Gstreamer 1.14.5 and the following commands are working: 
SENDER:   ./gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=C:/Users/danie/Desktop/0.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 

Receiver:  ./gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc  port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink

Comment: This is also working when I run the server in the Ubuntu and the receiver in windows. However, things are not working when I run this in the opposite way and when I run the same commands only at ubuntu. Same error: " reason not-negotiated (-4)"
Is this a problem with the GStremer version? I'm using the version 1.16.2 in ubuntu.

Comment: This is the error output when i set the debug to --gst-debug=1:

gst-launch-1.0 -v --gst-debug=1 udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink


ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
'